# MySql exception for many connection

Tags: mysql

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> MySqlException raised in OpenConnection, 
Host is blocked because of many connection errors; 
unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Do you have any idea why this exception comes up?

Comment: This line should tell you: `Host is blocked because of many connection errors;`

Comment: When i login into my application, i am blown up with this error, thats all i have for now.

Comment: Then is there any way to find how many connections are allowed in the server & how many are already used?

Comment: This isn't an issue with max_connections. The related configuration variable is max_connect_errors. However, you appear to be having network issues; that is, something wrong with your Internet connection. You will have to fix that first.

Comment: The free MySQL Workbench tool can show the list of active connections.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set a higher value to max_connections and max_connect_errors in my.cnf.

You can see more info about this error on [blocked-host](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/blocked-host.html) and [communication-errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/communication-errors.html)